# Unable to verify method called via Xunit Mock

Tags: c#, moq, moq-4

Using Moq 4.18.1 to test my C# code, I'm wanting to verify a method calls another method. In the class being tested I have this:

```cs
public class IntegratedPlatformRepository : PvRepository<OutputDTO>, IIntegratedPlatformRepository
{
    protected virtual async Task IpSpecificGetterExtras(OutputDTO dto, CancellationToken cancellationToken) { }

    public async Task<OutputDTO> GetAsync(Guid uid, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default) {
       var dto = ...
       await IpSpecificGetterExtras(dto, cancellationToken);
       ...
    }
```

I want to ensure that `IpSpecificGetterExtras` is called when `GetAsync` is called, so I tried this:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task GetAsync_Calls_IpSpecificGetterExtras()
{
    // Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IntegratedPlatformRepository> {
        CallBase = true
    };

    // Act
    await _repo.GetAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    // Assert
    mock
      .Protected()
      .Verify<Task>(
          "IpSpecificGetterExtras", Times.Once(),
          ItExpr.IsAny<OutputDTO>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
    );
}
```

If I simply run the test it fails saying the invocation wasn't performed. If I debug the test and set a breakpoint in `IpSpecificGetterExtras` the breakpoint is hit and I can step through the method, so it's definitely being called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the shown example `mock` was not invoked.

The test needs to be refactored to allow it to flow to completion so that it can be verified as expected.

```
[Fact]
public async Task GetAsync_Calls_IpSpecificGetterExtras() {
    // Arrange
    var mock = new Mock<IntegratedPlatformRepository> {
        CallBase = true
    };

    mock.Protected()
        .Setup<Task>("IpSpecificGetterExtras",
             ItExpr.IsAny<OutputDTO>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
        .Returns(Task.CompletedTask);

    var subject = mock.Object;

    // Act
    await subject.GetAsync(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());

    // Assert
    mock
        .Protected()
        .Verify<Task>(
            "IpSpecificGetterExtras", Times.Once(),
            ItExpr.IsAny<OutputDTO>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
        );
}
```